# Combine two Just values if present, else return first Just

Tags: haskell, option-type

I want  a shorter way to write this block of code as this is going to be used in multiple places in a project I am working on. Is there a library I can use which would have a function for my specific need?

```
case mbData1, mbData2 of
       (Just data1, Just data2) -> Just $ mergeData data1 data2
       (Nothing, Just data2) -> Just data2
       (Just data1, Nothing) -> Just data1
       (Nothing, Nothing) -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 11):

First, note that your expression only makes sense if `mergeData x y` has the same type as `x` and `y` each have, i.e. if its type is

```
mergeData :: X -> X -> X
```

for some concrete type `X`.

Given that, we can rely on Maybe's Applicative and Alternative instances:

```
mergeTwoMaybeDatas :: Maybe X -> Maybe X -> Maybe X
mergeTwoMaybeDatas a b = liftA2 mergeData a b <|> a <|> b
```

If you want to reuse this pattern many times but for different functions, and you think this is not clear, you could define a function parameterizing over `mergeData`.

But wait, maybe we can do something even simpler! If your `mergeData` function is associative (i.e., `mergeData x (mergeData y z) = mergeData (mergeData x y) z`), then your X type is a Semigroup, with `mergeData` as its combine operation. In that case, consider defining the Semigroup instance. Then you could use the tools designed for Semigroups to handle this even more simply.

```
data X = ...
instance Semigroup X where
  (<>) = mergeData

mergeTwoMaybeDatas :: Maybe X -> Maybe X -> Maybe X
mergeTwoMaybeDatas = (<>)
```

Amazing: if you give X its Semigroup instance, you don't even have to implement `mergeTwoMaybeDatas` at all - it's just how `(<>)` already behaves for a Semigroup lifted into Maybe.

I encourage giving your types instances of all the typeclasses they can reasonably support: you will find many generic tools like this then work on them "for free". Having a Semigroup instance will likely help out for some of your other uses of this X type as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `salign` function from [the `semialign` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semialign-1.2.0.1). Create a `Semigroup` instance for your type, with `(<>) = mergeData` (or inline its definition and just always call it this way), and then
just call `salign mbData1 mbData2`.

Comment: If the type has a Semigroup instance, why should we depend on a library to get `salign` when `(<>)` already does exactly what we want?